# I-94 status update after Mexico visit

Tags: usa

I have my H1B petition valid until December 31, 2018. I recently went for a trip to Mexico on July 7, 2017, via road. I did get an entry stamp from Mexico.

Before leaving the US, my I-94 admit date was January 10, 2019. I re-entered the US on July 9, 2017. I didn't get any stamp on my passport from CBP and there was no update on online of the I-94 when I checked several days later.

Now I am on vacation in India; I left the US on August 18, 2017, and when I checked my I-94, it has an updates that says my last entry was July 9, 2017 and the admit until date as July 10, 2017. Is there an issue with my status?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no issue with your status.

Technically at the moment you don't have "status". Once you left the US for India your status ended.  As your visa is still valid, when you re-enter the US you will be issued a new I94, and your status will become valid once again.

What almost certainly occured on your trip to Mexico is something called [Automatic Revalidation](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/automatic-revalidation.html).  Normally when you leave the US your status ends, and when you re-enter you are issued with a new I94.  Automatic Revalidation is a process where-by for short trips to a small number of neighboring countries (mainly Canada and Mexico) your status is deemed to have continued even whilst you were outside of the US, and thus when you re-enter your existing status continues as if you'd never left.  Your existing I94 is still valid, as is it's existing expiry date.

What you are seeing on the CBP website is most likely simply a case of the system incorrectly showing your auto-revalidation entry - fairly clearly the border officials would not have given you 1 day worth of status on entry.

Comment: "As your visa is still valid" It's not certain that their visa is still valid, because *if* they stayed past the date on their I-94, the visa would have automatically become void under INA 222(g). You are guessing that they didn't stay past the date on their I-94 because they were admitted on Automatic Revalidation, but we are not absolutely sure.

Comment: The online I94 checker is known to frequently show incorrect details for land border crossings, and in fact it's explicitly calls this fact out when you use it. Your claim is that a CBP officer may have allowed a H1-B entry holder to enter the US for 1 day, with no passport stamp, and without notifying him?  Even if that was the case, any such issues could be handled when re-entering the country (the visa is NOT automatically cancelled in the system, so they would still be able to board a flight to the US)

Comment: The visa is voided automatically by law if the person stayed past the date on their I-94; it doesn't matter what it is "in the system". It is not visible on the visa that it has been automatically voided, so yes they can board a flight, but that doesn't solve the issue that the visa may be void. I am not sure what you mean by "such issues could be handled" -- handled how? You are looking at it as a mistake that will be corrected; but it is permissible for them to admit him for a short period (i.e. not a mistake), in which case they would "handle" an invalid visa by denying him entry.

Comment: Well I have my return flight for Oct 2. I have already approached our visa team to check on the issue. I believe the online update of i94 doesn't happen right away once you enter US. I had checked for the update the very same day since they didn't put a stamp and it was still showing the old date. Am waiting to hear back from my employer

Comment: Last time I entered the US (last week) I checked my I94 about an hour after entering and it had updated.  I've seen the same previously as well.

Comment: Thanks Doc.. I didn't had any issues with immigration. As you mentioned it was an error due to automatic validation. I got my i94 updated after my latest new entry.